# I have error during fetching data from mongodb using c# .net

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://10.10.32.125:27017";
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new 
       MongoUrl(connectionString));
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        var Server = mongoClient.GetDatabase("mongovaibhav");
        var collection = Server.GetCollection<employee>("mongov");


        employee cd = new employee();
        foreach (employee employess in collection.Find({ fname: "vaibhav" }) )
        {

        }
```

I am getting error in `foreach` loop and `MongoCollection`.
how can I get the List of data?
[This error is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Hi7.png)

Comment: what is the error you are getting?Can you please post it here?

Comment: i am getting syntax error like "type casting" can you please show me the way how can i fetch data

Comment: You have to build you filter and give it as a parameter to `collection.Find()`

Comment: can you show me with example

Comment: You have my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a `filter`

```
var filter = Builders<employe>.Filter.Eq("fname", "vaibhav")
```

And then you can access your data using the `filter`

**first option**

```
foreach (employee employess in 
collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result )
{
  //do your computation
}
```

**Second option**

```
var employes = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
foreach(employe in employes)
{
  //do your computation
}
```

Comment: The link you provided is about the list in `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. but MongoDB C# Driver collection doesn't have `FindAll`method. Here is its [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1.htm).

Comment: exactly @Yared I cant Find Any FindAll Methiod

Comment: it is still showing me that "foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type mongoDb......"

Comment: @vaibhavpancholi, if it worked for you, don't forget to accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: yes i got data but how can i show them in a gride view because if i am trying to pass the employees object to gridbview its showing me that " it must be ither iListsources or iEnumbrebel"

Answer (score 0):

```
 string connectionString = "mongodb://10.10.32.125:27017";
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        var Server = mongoClient.GetDatabase("mongovaibhav");
        var collection = Server.GetCollection<employee>("mongov");
        var filter = Builders<employee>.Filter.Eq("fname", "vaibhav");
        List<employee> emp = new List<employee>();
       foreach (var emp1 in collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result )
        {
            emp.Add(emp1);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = emp;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

i Get The Solution Thank you All Of You and special @edkeveked